# how to pick a record from table in the below format?

Tags: sql

table:

```
id  status date
133 start  22/05/2018
133 end    22/05/2018
133 start  23/05/2018
133 end    23/05/2018
```

i want the query to display the record like this.

```
id  intime      outtime
133 22/05/2018  22/05/2018
133 23/05/2018  23/05/2018
```

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, ect...) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and do aggregation :

```
select id, max(case when status = 'start' then date end) as intime,
           max(case when status = 'end' then date end) as outtime
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by status order by date) as seq
      from table
     ) t
 group by id, seq;
```

You haven't tagged any `DBMS` but most of DBMS has analytical function.